# How to make a constant json array with JSON Simple

Tags: json-simple

I'm looking to make a very simple object with JSONSimple, that uses a constant array:

```
{
 "user":"fei0x",
 "permissions":[10,20]
}
```

How do I construct the array portion?

I tried to use a primitive array, but instead it creates an object with each element it's own attribute.

```
myJsonObj.put("permissions", [10,20] );
```

produces

```
{
 "user":"fei0x",
 "permissions":
    {
      "0":10,
      "1":20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create JSONArray object to put array node

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("user", "fei0x");

// if you have const array then loop over to add elements in following object
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

 //loop over
for (int index=0; index < constArray.length; index++) {
   list.add(constArray[index]);
}

obj.put("permissions", list)
```

Comment: Oh right, for some reason I got it stuck in my head I could only put JSONObject in there. Makes sense, works, Thanks.